# How to start the LXQT launcher (lxqt-runner) with just the Super key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxqt, launcher, super-key

***Posted in order to give the answer (QnA).***

---

I have installed Lxqt desktop on top of Kubuntu 18.04. That means I can still use the `krunner` launcher of KDE/Plasma if I chose to, but Lxqt has its own launcher called "runner" (lxqt-runner) that is similar and very light.

[image]

It is supposed to be used with Alt-F1. That can be changed in the Shortcut Key settings but not to just the Super-key.

Is it possible to make this launcher run with only the Super key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### LXQt 0.12:

Install the `ksuperkey` program as indicated [here](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey).

Just running `ksuperkey` would asign the Super key to the program that was already set to run with the shortcut Alt-F1. The latter can be changed (see the link or the readme file), but in the present case we don't need to do that, only be sure that Alt-F1t is precisely the shortcut of the lxqt-runner under Shortcut Keys settings:

[image]

Then add `ksuperkey` at the list of startup programs under Session Settings/Autostart:

[image]

---

### LXQt 0.13:

The Super key (Super_L) can be assigned as such from *Shortcut Keys* settings.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Press Alt-F1 to see the main menu, then type in "Shortcut" to see the application "Shortcut Keys".  After you launch it, find the first entry that says "Show/hide runner dialog" (it's already there and it's bound to the keystroke Alt-F2.  What you want to do is edit it and change it to the Super key.